# how to create n-1-dimensional collections easily from an n-dimensional set?

Tags: python, numpy

I use data in the numpy array format, for example:

```
[[5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2]
[4.9 3. 1.4 0.2]
[4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2]
[4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2]
......
[5.9 3. 5.1 1.8]]
```

I need n n-1-dimensional array (where n is the number of dimensions), in this case four 3-dimensional data sets.

The first collection:

```
[[3.5 1.4 0.2]
[3. 1.4 0.2]
[3.2 1.3 0.2]
[3.1 1.5 0.2]
......
[3. 5.1 1.8]]
```

Second collection:

```
[[5.1 1.4 0.2]
[4.9 1.4 0.2]
[4.7 1.3 0.2]
[4.6 1.5 0.2]
......
[5.9 5.1 1.8]]
```

e.t.c.

Until now, I have used the numpy.hstack () function, which requires parameters in the form of tuples. I did it like this:

```
a = []
for i in range (0.3):
   a.append (tuple (map (tuple, D [:, i: i + 1])))
```

The first collection:

```
numpy.hstack ([a[1], a[2], a[3])
```

Second set:

```
numpy.hstack ([a[0], a[2], a[3])
```

e.t.c.

The problem appears in collections with more dimensions - then they can't be created by hand.
I wanted to do it in a loop like this:

```
dim = 4
flag = True
for k in range (0, dim-1):
b = []
for l in range (0, dim-1):
   if l! = k:
      if flag:
         b = a[l]
         flag = False
      else:
         b = numpy.hstack ([b, a[l]])
```

Unfortunately, the hstack () function requires files with the same number of dimensions, so I can not combine a 2d set with 1d, etc.
Does anyone know how to create n-1-dimensional collections easily from an n-dimensional set?

Comment: One 'colleciton' looks like `D[:,[1,2,3]]` (or `D[:, 2:]`), the next `D[:, [0,2,3]]`.  It's not clear where you are try to go from there, whether it's a list of these or something else.  `D` is 2d, and so are each of these copies.  I don't think you are talking about getting 1d subsets from a 2d, but rather getting subsets of the columns of `D`; subsets of length 3 from 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays) :

```
 mask=~np.eye(dim,dtype=bool)
```

now   `D[:,mask[i]]`  is your i-th collection.

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.combinations` is handy way of generating column index combinations:

```
In [182]: itertools.combinations(range(4),3)
Out[182]: <itertools.combinations at 0x7f7dc41cb5e8>
In [183]: list(_)
Out[183]: [(0, 1, 2), (0, 1, 3), (0, 2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

Using that to generate subarrays of `D`:

```
In [184]: D = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [185]: alist = []
In [186]: for tup in itertools.combinations(range(4),3):
     ...:     alist.append(D[:, tup])
     ...:     
In [187]: alist
Out[187]: 
[array([[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 4,  5,  6],
        [ 8,  9, 10]]), 
 array([[ 0,  1,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 11]]), 
 array([[ 0,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  6,  7],
        [ 8, 10, 11]]), 
 array([[ 1,  2,  3],
        [ 5,  6,  7],
        [ 9, 10, 11]])]
```

I'm not quite sure what you were trying to do with `hstack`. Combining these subarrays into one wide one probably isn't what you want:

```
In [188]: np.hstack(alist)
Out[188]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  0,  1,  3,  0,  2,  3,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  4,  5,  7,  4,  6,  7,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10,  8,  9, 11,  8, 10, 11,  9, 10, 11]])
```